# Setting packages version using pip in a conda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda, virtual-environment

**Background:**

I've been working on a server last year as a part of a student project. Now the server is being changed and unfortunately, a piece of code that  I'd written is failed to pass a test. I don't have access to the server (because of security issues) but the good news is I have the scripts as well as the packages (and their version) which are installed on the new server. So I've decided to install all the packages on the server on my own local machine in an environment to imitate the server.

**Problem**:
Since not all the packages are available with conda (or channels need to be specified) I decided to make a conda environment and install all the packages with pip. Once I create the environment, conda installs a bunch of packages (like `wheel`,`pip`,`ipython`, `certifi`, etc.). But I need a certain (older) version of them. So I tried to override them by `pip install -U <package_name>==<version>`.  But for some packages, I ended up with two different versions: one the default version installed by conda at the environment creation, and the other one with pip. And now, when I run my code, I'm not sure which version of those packages are being used. So I want to keep only one version: the one which is installed via pip!

**Question(s)**:

1. How can I uninstall the packages that are installed with conda while keeping the pip ones? I used `conda remove <package_name>` with the expectation that only conda-installed packages would be wiped, yet that wasn't the case and both were gone for good!
2. How to override a conda-installed version via pip? I know conda is made to  avoid this action to protect the environment from getting messy, but in my case it leads me to another question,
3. How in the first place, can I make the environment exactly the same as the server so that I don't deal with conda/pip packages any more?

Comment: Currently, the question is rather generic, though still limited enough for decent answers, IMO. However, I worry the answers may be more tip-oriented and not end up resolving your specific situation. It might be helpful to share the list of packages (with versions), so that prospective answerers can more precisely address whatever problems might arise. That is, then users can provide a suggested best practice for how they would approach the env replication (answer question 3 directly).